# Constructors calling other constructors gives an error

Tags: java, javafx

This seems like this should just work. This is being compiled as part of a JavaFX application. I have several constructor classes with different arguments, but effectively they are very similar to one another.

The first is a `String, String, String` constructor and the second is a `String, String, String, int`. I wanted to just write the `String, String, String`, and then make a minor adjustment to the `String, String, String, int` variant and call the original constructor. I get an error that says:

```
error: cannot find symbol
this.DataLineRegister(new_register_name,new_register_model,new_register_default);
   symbol: method DataLineRegister(String,String,String)
1 error
```

Here is the code. I have tried with and without the `this` reference.  Also, tried `self`, but I guess that might only be a C thing.

```
public DataLineRegister (String new_register_name, String new_register_model, String new_register_default) {
  register_name = new_register_name;
  register_model = new_register_model;

  try {
     register_default = new BigInteger(new_register_default,16);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     System.out.println("Input is not a hexadecimal number");
  }
}

public DataLineRegister (String new_register_name, String new_register_model, String new_register_default, int new_bit_width) {
    defaultRegisterBitWidth = new_bit_width;
    this.DataLineRegister(new_register_name, new_register_model, new_register_default);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The syntax for calling a sister constructor is just `this(arguments)`. Not `this.Classname(arguments)`.

Comment: First, you should learn the Java language naming convention of variables. Java uses camelCase to name variables. For example, `new_register_name` should be `newRegisterName`. Second, calling constructors within the same class should be done by using `this( args )`

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write `this(new_register_name,new_register_model,new_register_default);` instead. That is the correct syntax for calling a *delegated constructor*.

Also, note that it has to be the *first* statement in the constructor body.